# How to determine IP version in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, ipv6

I want to support both versions IPv4 and IPv6. Currently. I only support IPv4, but in order to set different behaviour for each version of IP I need to know, what version of IP I am working with.

Currenly I am using `gethostbyname` function, and depending on `h_addrtype` field of `hostent struct` I set whether it is IPv4 or IPv6, but I am wondering is that really correct? And if it is not, what are possible ways to get IP version ? And if it is correct, what should I do, if this function fails ?

Thanks on advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `h_addrtype` field of an IPv6 address should be `AF_INET6` (instead of `AF_INET`) and testing that field is the correct method when using `gethostbyname`.

You should however consider using `getaddrinfo` instead of `gethostbyname` in new applications.

Comment: I wonder if he needs to worry about v4/v6 difference at all when he uses `getaddrinfo` (and perhaps `sockaddr_storage`)

Comment: @nodakai that's a fair point - in theory if you use `getaddrinfo` the code will "just work" regardless of whether the host is on IPv4 or IPv6.

Comment: I suspect theory often differs from practice ? =)

Comment: Yes, in theory, they're the same, but in practise, they're not ;-)

Answer (score 6):

`gethostbyname` is deprecated, you should actually use [`getaddrinfo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getaddrinfo), one of the reasons it's being deprecated are IPv4/IPv6 issues.

That being said, yes, checking `h_addrtype` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getsockname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html) to determine IP version,

```
int getsockname(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

Below method can be employed,

```
/* Function to detect family of a socket */
// Return AF_INET or AF_INET6
unsigned short GetSocketFamily(int sockfd)
{
    unsigned short sa[16];  // 32 bytes is enough for sockaddr version for any family
                            // 16 bytes for IPv4 and 28 bytes for IPv6
    socklen_t lth = sizeof(sa);
    getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &lth);
    return sa[0]; // In any case (IPv4 or IPv6) family is the first halfword of 
                  // address structure
}
```

Comment: as far as I understand for your method I will need an open socket already, that is not acceptable in my case.